# UserSecrets fail when ran under live testing feature of Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I have UserSecrets working correctly on my .NET 2.0 Core Web API. I also have it working correctly for my integration test suite against this same web API using the test server based on the function below (all tests pass). The problem occurs when I use the new live testing feature. I am already using the new extension method that was previously documented to handle this type of bug, so I'm not sure what else to change. If I move the settings back to the regular appsetting.json and remove the AddUserSecrets call, live testing works as expected (but obviously I don't want to do that).

```
    public static TestServer CreateServer()
    {
        var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => config.AddUserSecrets<Startup>())
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => services.AddOptions()
            .Configure<AppSettings>(context.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")))
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
        return server;
    }
```

Message:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Could not find
>   'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly 'RouteManager.Core.Server'. Check
>   that the project for 'RouteManager.Core.Server' has set the
>   'UserSecretsId' build property. If the 'UserSecretsId' property is
>   already set then add a reference to the
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets package.